# How to hide a column in yii

Tags: yii

I want to hide a column in yii based on a condition. I have used a function in model. but visible functionality is not working in this column.

```
     $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridview', array(
            'id'=>'gridview',
            'dataProvider'=>$dp,
                          'columns'=>array(
                        array(
                            'header' => 'Entries',
                            'value' => '$data->entry_name'
                        ),
                        array(
                            'name' => 'value',

                            'value' => '$data->entry_name',
                            'visible'=>'$data->show()',    
                            'type'=>'raw'
                        ),
                      )
              )
        );
```

function in Model

```
public function show()
{
.........
return 1 or 0;

}
```

but it not working. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a condition anywhere yet. You should use a comparison operator like `return $this->attribute !== null;` in your show function. Which returns true if attribute contains some value. Or if you want to do it on random you can `return rand(0,1) == 1;`.

Comment: public function show(){ $c = Model::model()->findbypk($this->id); if($c){return 1} else{ return 0} }

Comment: i have used this code in my function and return 0 or 1 but it is not working yet

Comment: `return 1 or 0;` is always equal to `return 1;` and if you check if a model exists with id being equal to the id of the current model, then that will also be always true.

Comment: you do see you are checking whether or not an already existing model exists? Since you request a model with id equal to $this->id (current AR pk)

Comment: in other words, `$c` will always be set and the function will always `return true;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107520/discussion-between-ttdijkstra-and-mamta).